# PHP appending to file from specific position

Tags: php, pointers, append, fseek

In php i am opening a text file and appending to it. However I need to append 3 chars before the end of file.
In other words i need to append/write from a specific place in the file.

Can any one help?

Best Regards 
Luben

Comment: Please show us your code. And take a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fseek.php

Comment: For every non-french speaking here: http://php.net/fseek

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to open the file for edit, seek to the desired position and then write to the file, eg.:

```
<?php
  $file = fopen($filename, "c");
  fseek($file, -3, SEEK_END);
  fwrite($file, "whatever you want to write");
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Further reference at [php.net - fseek doc](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong! I tried that before I posted here, I should have mentioned that. If you open a file with a or a+ it will append to the end regardless of fseek() or rewind(). Read the notes ant the bottom of the link you posted. Another thing if I use w or w+ it simply starts from the beginning. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The bottom of the article also states that by opening the file in 'r+' you should be able to use fseek()

Comment: @Luben you are right, I haven't read it properly. The correct mode is "c" or "c+" (or you can use "r+", as @Neil Aitken said :)), as stated in [link](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) I have edited the response to reflect it.

Comment: @Neil Aitken && @Erbureth Thanks so much for the help guys! You are both right. r+ and c or c+ work perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a short text file and you are only doing this once you can read in the contents (with fread()), store it only upto 3 chars from the end using substring and then append your new content onto the end of that and write.

But as I say if this is a regular thing and/or with large files, this isn't the best approach. I'll have a think.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Alex B!
I didn't think of that and it may be a solution. But I'm afraid the files might get pretty big....say up to 1000 chars. If I can't find anything else I'll create a dummy file and do some tests.

Comment: @Luben: 1000 characters are around 1kB (in ascii 1 character = 1 Byte). Its safe to read it completely into the memory.

Comment: Thanks King! Ideally I want to use Erbureth's method that he mentions above but unfortunately that doesn't work. I will look around and if not tomorrow I'll do as you say.