# Laravel 4: append data to file

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-4

I have "array()" file, and I need to append data in specific char from the end, ex: append to -3 char from end

```
<?php
//arr_data.php

return array(
    'key1'  =>  'value1',
    'key2'  =>  'value2',
    'key3'  =>  'value3',
    'key4'  =>  'value4',

    //insert new data here
);
```

I know, can append to the file end using Filesystem:

```
Filesystem::append( "/dir/path", "'key5'    =>  'value5',")
```

but how to append in specific char from end?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could use `File::getRequire();` to get the value of the array in the file, then append your data to the array and write it back out to the same file.

```
$data = File::getRequire('arr_data.php');
$data[] = array('key5'    =>  'value5');
$string = "<?php return" . var_export($data) . "; ?>";
File::put('arr_data.php',$string );
```

Comment: but I expect "arr_data.php" to be very large array

Answer (score 0):

I found answer outside Laravel:

```
<?php
  $file = fopen($filename, "c");
  fseek($file, -3, SEEK_END);
  fwrite($file, "whatever you want to write");
  fclose($file);
?>
```

[PHP appending to file from specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979274/php-appending-to-file-from-specific-position)