# How to truncate a file at the beginning in PHP?

Tags: php, file, logging, filesize, truncate

I have a simple logger class written in PHP. The file it writes to should have a maximum size. I know I can truncate a file with `ftruncate($filename, $size)`, but this removes content at the end. So what I'd like to do is the following:

```
if(filesize($filename) > $mySize) {
  //remove X bytes at BEGINNING of $filename
}

// append log message
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a+');
if($handle !== false) {
  fwrite($handle, $myMessage);
  fclose($handle);
}
```

So that the log "scrolls" through the file over time, instead of growing ad infinitum (and in the end crashing at 2GB, the `signed int` limit of PHP).

What is the best approach to remove beginnings of a file without having to worry to much about performance? I assume reading a file line by line into another cache file is slow, especially if the logging happens rather often. Is there any better way?

Comment: Can't you just rotate logs instead of just reusing the same file over and over and remove old logs after x amount of time?

Comment: @JonStirling This is a possibility I also considered, maybe I'll do log rotation. But still I'm interested in the answert to my question, even if just out of curiosity. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have taken in the past for this sort of simple logger is to have a standard record size.  I then use that standard record size along with the record index to compute a file offset to where to write the log record.

Usually I use the first record to contain the current record index of where to put the next record followed by a comma and then the maximum number of records.

So the basic logic is

- check if log file exists, if not initialize record index and max index values
- when adding record, read first record to get current index and max index
- compute file offset and `fseek()` to that point and write record
- increment the current index, `fseek()` to the first record and update index record
- close file

The main thing is to have a complete, space or blank filled record of the proper size so that all of your record offsets line up and when you view the file with a text editor, it is all text.  Also make sure that a new line is on the end of the record to make it easy to view and each record is on a new line in the text viewer, whether editor or other application such as a web browser.

Finally as part of increment do a modulus to force a rollover since you want it to be a circular buffer.  Just make sure that you add one as you want your index to be from 1 to n (where n is max number of records) because record 0, the first record, is used to contain the current index and max number of records.

For mechanism to open, seek to, write, and close a file with PHP see [PHP appending to file from specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979274/php-appending-to-file-from-specific-position).